# TINYMCE not sending editor content via AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, html, tinymce

I have implemented TINYMCE editor but the problem is that what I try to process the data entered and edited via the editor through AJAX it doesn't sends the data. In console when I `console.log(dataString)` it shows that the data is being sent empty.

Form

```
<form method="post" action="">
  <textarea class="form-control" id="formem"></textarea>
  <textarea class="form-control" id="foradv"></textarea>
</form>
```

AJAX

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submit").click(function() {
    var dataString = {
      formem: $('#formem').val(),
      foradv: $('#foradv').val(),
      type: 'homeData'
    };
    console.log(dataString);
    var $submit = $(this).parent().find('#submit');
    $.confirm({
      title: 'Confirm!',
      content: 'Are you sure you want to delete this banner?',
      buttons: {
        confirm: function () {
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            //dataType : "json",
            url: "cms-process.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: true,
            beforeSend: function(){
              $submit.val("Please wait...");
            },
            success: function(html){
              $.alert(html);
              $submit.val("Update Content");
            }
          });
        },
        cancel: function(){}
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
</script>
```

TinyMCE Loaded in  tag and editor is seen well.

```
<script src="js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>
    tinymce.init({
        selector:'textarea',
        height : "300",
        plugins: "textcolor",
        toolbar: "undo redo | bold italic underline justify | styleselect | forecolor backcolor | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify",
        textcolor_cols: "10"
    });
</script>
```

Console after clicking send shows empty data being sent.

```
Object { formem: "", foradv: "", type: "homeData" }
```

Comment: on form submission, use `$('#mytextarea').text(tinymce.activeEditor.getContent());` to get the content instead of .val and obviously change #mytextarea with your text area id's

Comment: No use, `setup: function (editor) {
            editor.on('change', function () {
                tinymce.triggerSave();
            });
        }` See for example: http://jsfiddle.net/9euk9/374/